# Hiding new pages from being created in Wagtail

Tags: django, wagtail

I have tried searching the official documentation and related message boards for this however I have been unable to find anything related.

Some of the templates for pages in my website are only to be used once - e.g. homepage.

Is there a way in Wagtail to hide or disallow users from selecting that template/Page model when creating a new page?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can limit the places it is possible to create a page type, by editing `YourPageModel.parent_page_types`, see http://docs.wagtail.io/en/v1.10.1/reference/pages/model_reference.html#wagtail.wagtailcore.models.Page.parent_page_types. Similarly there is a `subpage_types` setting, so for instance you can enforce that `NewsIndexPage` can only be created as a direct child of `HomePage`, and can only contain `NewsItemPage` instances. Combining this with user permissions should be enough for home pages or page types at a high enough place in the tree.

<del>If you absolutely must enforce that only one of a certain page type exists, it is possible to override the classmethod `clean_parent_page_models`, to return `[]` if an instance of this class already exists. This approach is a hack, however, and may be broken by future versions of Wagtail.</del>

---

Update, January 2021:

The hack above isn't exactly *broken*, but it certainly wasn't ideal, and since version 2.4 Wagtail has had the `max_count` Page attribute (and `max_count_per_parent` in 2.5).

Documentation: https://docs.wagtail.io/en/stable/reference/pages/model_reference.html#wagtail.core.models.Page.max_count

@JaredOzzy's answer is correct, and has more details on these methods.

Comment: Awesome, thanks! Shame that this is not included in the tutorial :/ -- although now I guess anyone who Google searches this will find this post!

Comment: Good suggestion. Pull requests are always welcomed. https://github.com/wagtail/wagtail/blob/master/docs/getting_started/tutorial.rst

Answer (score 2):

Anybody coming here looking for something similar, Wagtail has now added 2 nifty properties that we can use to limit pages from being created more than a specific amount of times.

http://docs.wagtail.io/en/v2.5.1/reference/pages/model_reference.html#wagtail.core.models.Page.max_count

**max_count**

> Controls the maximum number of pages of this type that can be created through the Wagtail administration interface. This is useful when needing “allow at most 3 of these pages to exist”, or for singleton pages.

and 
**max_count_per_parent**.

> Controls the maximum number of pages of this type that can be created under any one parent page.